# The method setFragment(Fragment) in the type FacebookButtonBase is not applicable for the arguments (MainFragment)

Tags: android, facebook, android-fragments

Implementing a FaceBook Login Button Having errors with

"The method setFragment(Fragment) in the type FacebookButtonBase is not applicable for the arguments (MainFragment)"

for the code line

"loginButton.setFragment(this);"

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    LoginButton loginButton = (LoginButton) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);

    loginButton.setReadPermissions("users_friends");

    loginButton.setFragment(this);

    loginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, mCallback);
}
```

Much Obliged for the feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks,

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

not the other

import android.app.Fragment;